# Master Yoda's decision making regarding the use of the Force

Tags: star-wars

At the end of Episode II: when Yoda was fighting Count Dooku, couldn't Master Yoda use the Force to pull out Anakin and Obi-Wan instead of trying to prevent the tower from falling over the unconscious Anakin and Obi-Wan? Failing to do so, Dooku escaped during Yoda's attempt to save them.

Comment: It's more likely that instead of trying to manipulate two separate bodies, he chose to focus on one falling item.

Comment: Very wise, he is. :D

Comment: Hm, two bodies weighting less than 200kg total, for half a second, vs a pillar/tower (apparently) weighting much more and for an extended period of time? Note that if the number of bodies really matters more than the weight, he could as well have *pushed* the tower so that it falls 1m behind the Jedi. But there can be a variety of reasons: for example, that the damage caused by the pillar hitting the ground would have been too important, or that he wanted to give immediate medical assistance to Anakin and Obi-Wan anyway, or that he "knew" that he could not reasonably hope to stop Dooku...

Comment: The tower would have landed and rolled.

Comment: you also dont want to just whip around 2 ingured guys, and throw them across the room.

Comment: @T.Verron, I recall from Yoda's teaching to Luke in The Empire Strikes Back that **size/weight** doesn't matter (scene lifting a X-wing from Dagobah's swamp).

Comment: @Deion I always thought it was implying "... given enough time". Otherwise, basic physics would show that he claims the same thing as Palpatine in RotS: "unlimited power". Joke aside, I'd still say it is more of a mantra than a physics theorem. (For the record: https://what-if.xkcd.com/3/ )

Comment: The big question is: Why was he rotating his wrists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no in-universe canon answer. The movie of course doesn't supply one.

Neither does the R.A. Salvatore's novelization, really:

> “The battle is far from over!” Dooku stubbornly argued. “This is just the beginning!” Reaching into the Force, he took hold of one of the huge cranes within the hangar and threw it down at Obi-Wan and Anakin.
>
> “Anakin!” Obi-Wan cried. He grabbed at the plummeting crane with the Force, and Anakin, startled awake, did so, as well. Even working together, they hadn’t the strength left to stop its crushing descent.
>
> But Yoda did.
>
> Yoda grabbed the crane and held it fast, but in doing so, he had to release Dooku. The Count wasted no time, sprinting away, leaping up the ramp to his sail ship. As Yoda began to move the fallen crane harmlessly aside, the sail ship’s engine roared to life, and all three Jedi watched helplessly as Count Dooku blasted away.

We can take a couple of guesses though:

1. They didn't know where the crane would land. Simply moving Anakin wouldn't have necessarily helped
2. It's a basic precept of emergency/trauma medicine, that moving an injured person - especially with the significant amount of force needed to quickly yank someone from under the falling crane - may significantly worsen them.
3. Even leaving that aside, a Force Push could injure a person in general, if it was done too hard/fast. Human body is fragile.
4. On Yoda's part, he already had Obi-Wan concentrating on moving the column. So he was better off joining that effort rather than doing his own with unpredictable results and interplay of the Force pushes in 2 different directions.
5. "Size matters not". For Yoda, lifting the crane may have been just as easy weight-wise as to lift a human.

Now that we said all of guessing, the real reason is one that is **always** explicitly stated in Star Wars material for actions of a Jedi in battle - **Yoda wasn't thinking logically or making considered decisions. He was following the flow and the will of the Force.**